# c++ call of virtual base function is ignored

Tags: c++

i have a base class

```
class DLL_IMPORTEXPORT Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(Base *parentItem = NULL);
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual bool initFromXml(const pugi::xml_node &xml_node);
    //....
};
```

as well as a derived class

```
class DLL_IMPORTEXPORT Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived(Base *parentItem = 0);
    ~Derived();

    bool initFromXml(const pugi::xml_node &xml_node);
    //...
};
```

now i want to call the base class method

```
virtual bool initFromXml(const pugi::xml_node &xml_node);
```

from the derived class method

```
bool Derived::initFromXml(const pugi::xml_node &xml_node)
{
    bool all_ok = false;

    // .... do some specific things

    // then run the base class method
    all_ok = all_ok && Base::initFromXml(xml_node);

    return all_ok;
}
```

It all compiles fine, however, when i execute the code the base class methode is not executed and when i try to step into it in the debugger it does't step into it and just ignores it. I'm a bit confused. where is my brain-bug?

Comment: This is why an explicit `if` is better than a "clever" one line statement.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers to future questions --- looks like you're already set on this one :) .

Comment: Is there something that sets `all_ok` to a true value?  If we compile your code as-is, then of course `Base::initFromXml()` will not be called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression:

```
all_ok && Base::initFromXml(xml_node)
```

uses the logical operator `&&` which has *short-circuit evaluation*, i.e.: if `all_ok` is false `Base::initFromXml()` won't called, since the result of the whole expression can be already determined: false.

---

If you really want to call `Base::initFromXml()` regardless of the value of `all_ok`, then you can either swap the order of the operands in the expression above, that is:

```
Base::initFromXml(xml_node) && all_ok
```

or call the function in a separate statement and save its return value:

```
...
bool res_init = Base::initFromXml(xml_node);
all_ok = all_ok && res_init;
```

As suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302299/c-call-of-virtual-base-function-is-ignored/48302342#comment83589482_48302342), using the bitwise *and*-operator (`&`) instead of the logical *and*-operator (`&&`) would be also a solution, since it does not short-circuit:

```
all_ok = all_ok & Base::initFromXml(xml_node);
```

Comment: You can also just switch the order between the function call and `all_ok`.

Comment: You could also use the & operator; which can't short circuit